# IntellijIdea : "package does not exist" from imported jar library

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Despite autocompleting working and no errors being shown, I can't used jar libraries imported in my IntellijIdea project, whatever the library or the project: compiling gives me a "package xxx does not exist"

The problem seems to be common but none of the solutions I finded on stack overflow or anywhere else worked (reinstalled intellijIdea, invalidate caches...). I ask again, maybe someone has a new magic solution.

I'm using the "Minecraft development" plugin (spigot API) and try to import another plugin as a dependency. IntellijIdea version: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve]? Where does the jar live, how do you point the compiler to it / how do you build?

Comment: I'm simply creating a new IntellijIdea project, add a new library using Files | Project Structures | Libairies | Add a library

My librairies folder looks like a single file which contains the PATH of the .jar (the path is correct I checked). I then import the class from automatic completion import, Intellij does detect the package but doesn't compile.